# scale an image keeping the aspect ratio without falling below the targets

Tags: java, image

I wonder if anybody can help me with the math/pseudo code/java code to scale an image to a target dimension. the requirement is to keep the aspect ratio, but not falling below the target dimension on both x and y scales. the final calculated dimension can be greater than the requested target but it needs to be the the closest one to the target.

example:
I have an image that is 200x100. it needs to be scaled down to a target dimension 30x10.
i need to find the minimal dimension that keeps the aspect ratio of the origin where both x and y scales are at least what is specified in the target.
in our example, 20x10 is not good because the x scale fell below the target (which is 30).
the closest one would be 30x15

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
targetRatio = targetWidth / targetHeight;
sourceRatio = sourceWidth / sourceHeight;
if(sourceRatio >= targetRatio){ // source is wider than target in proportion
    requiredWidth = targetWidth;
    requiredHeight = requiredWidth / sourceRatio;      
}else{ // source is higher than target in proportion
    requiredHeight = targetHeight;
    requiredWidth = requiredHeight * sourceRatio;      
}
```

This way your final image :

- always fits inside the target whereas not being cropped.
- keeps its original aspect ratio.
- and always has either the width or height (or both) exactly matching the target's.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). But what I need is that both width and height always match the target counter part or be greater than it. a fit is accepted only if it matches exactly, otherwise it should be greater. and when it goes greater, i needed to find the minimal one that is greater and yet keeps the aspect ratio.

Comment: I clicked enter and it posted so i modified my comment. the solution is partially full as in some cases one of the dimensions can fall below the target.

Comment: ok, in that case you just invert my if/else blocks of code and it'll work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your example you kind off already used the algorithm you're looking for.
I will use the example you have given.

```
Original          Target
200 x 100   ->    30 x 10

1. You take the bigger value of the target dimensions (in our case 30)
2. Check if its smaller than the corresponding original width or height
  2.1 If its smaller define this as the new width (So 30 is the new width)
  2.2 If its not smaller check the other part
3. Now we have to calculate the height which is simply the (30/200)*100

So as result you get like you wrote: 30 x 15
```

Hope this was clear :)

In the coding part you could use the **BufferedImage** and simply create a new BufferedImage with the correct scale value like that.

```
BufferedImage before = getBufferedImage(encoded);
int w = before.getWidth();
int h = before.getHeight();
BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(2.0, 2.0); // <-- Here you should use the calculated scale factors
AffineTransformOp scaleOp = 
new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
after = scaleOp.filter(before, after);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was checking darma's reply and comments in my IDE.this is very clear and correct too. Thank you very much. is it possible to accept two answers ?